# Convert NUMBER to different format - NUMFORMAT(MyPrice, '$ ###.###,##')

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking something similar to using in the BigQuery:
`NUMFORMAT(MyPrice, '$###.###,##')`

Example: `NUMFORMAT(99999999.99, '$###.###,##')`

Result: `99.999.999,99`

P.S. By not using JavaScripts and e.t.c.

Comment: This is NOT duped, WHY? As this current question involved ONLY BIG-QUERY

Comment: As far as I understand the only way is to do it through REGEX

Comment: i thought it is exact same as referenced question also have bigquery tag

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant It was for bigquery but now I try to figure out how to do it by not using JavaScript and e.t.c.... I'm a bit shocked that Google does not have a native function for this, as it is kind of essential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is in pure SQL (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION NUMFORMAT(number FLOAT64) AS (
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMAT("%'.2f", number), r'([\d,]+).(\d+)', r'\1=\2'), ',', '.'), '=', ',')
);
SELECT 
  NUMFORMAT(99999.99), 
  NUMFORMAT(99999999.99),
  NUMFORMAT(12345678.09),
  NUMFORMAT(-999.99)
```

with output

```
Row f0_         f1_             f2_             f3_  
1   99.999,99   99.999.999,99   12.345.678,09   -999,99
```

Comment: Causing issues with negative numbers  -999.99

Comment: with `9999999.99` = `,9.999.999,99`

Comment: With an updated version for positive value = `9.999.999.99` but it should be `9.999.999,99`

Comment: Please check Example and result in my question

Comment: Found Solution - `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT("%'.2f", -99999999.77),',','X'),'.',','),'X','.')`

Comment: Oh boy - I see now what you mean. that was typo just in typing output within my answer. Please double check and let me know. PS. from you previous comment - I though you expect to convert 9.999.999.99 to 9.999.999,99 - which obviously not supported in this answer at all